# disallow comments if they contain "http:" or "www." etc. in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dialog, chat, alert, spam

I'm working on a chat app and I'm trying to prevent spam. I obviously don't want people posting links to other websites so I want to not allow comments if they contain certain things like "http:" "https:" "www." ".com" ".net" ".org" etc. Is it possible to have an alert box pop up if the comment contains those types of words it it? Below is the code I use to run the chat app:

Javascript:

```
// render all of our messages in the ui
Template.chatBox.helpers({
  "messages": function() {
    return chatCollection.find();
  }
});

// get the value for handlerbar helper user
Template.chatMessage.helpers({
  "user": function() {
    if(this.userId == 'me') {
      return this.userId;
    } else if(this.userId) {
      getUsername(this.userId);
      return Session.get('user-' + this.userId);
    } else {
      return 'anonymous-' + this.subscriptionId;
    }
  }
});

// when Send Chat clicked at the message to the collection
Template.chatBox.events({
    "click #send": function() {
            if (Meteor.user() == null) {
              alert("You must login to post");
            return;
          }
            $('#messages').animate({"scrollTop": $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
            var message = $('#chat-message').val();

            // check to see if the message has any characters in it
            if (message.length < 1) {
              alert("You must enter a message to post.");
            return;
          }

            if (message.length > 200) {
              alert("Your message is too long... they can't read that fast!");
            return;
          }

            chatCollection.insert({
                userId: 'me',
                message: message
            });
            $('#chat-message').val('');

            //Validation
            var bot =Check_bots();

            if(bot==false)
            {    
            //add the message to the stream
            chatStream.emit('chat', message);
       }
        else
        {
            alert("Slow down! No need to post that fast.");
            return false;
        }
    },

    "keypress #chat-message": function(e) {
        if (Meteor.user() == null) {
            alert("You must login to post");
            return;
        }
        if (e.which == 13) {

          //Validation
       var bot =Check_bots();

        if(bot==false)
        {
            $('#messages').animate({"scrollTop": $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
            console.log("you pressed enter");
            e.preventDefault();
            //repeat function from #send click event here
            var message = $('#chat-message').val();

            // check to see if the message has any characters in it
            if (message.length < 1) {
              alert("You must enter a message to post.");
            return;
          }

          if (message.length > 200) {
              alert("Your message is too long... they can't read that fast!");
            return;
          }

            chatCollection.insert({
                userId: 'me',
                message: message
            });
            $('#chat-message').val('');

            //add the message to the stream
            chatStream.emit('chat', message);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Slow down! No need to post that fast.");
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
});

chatStream.on('chat', function(message) {
  chatCollection.insert({
    userId: this.userId,
    subscriptionId: this.subscriptionId,
    message: message
  });
});

var lastintime=0;
var defference=0;
var msg_count=0;

function Check_bots()
{
    var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    seconds=parseInt(seconds);

    if(lastintime < seconds)
    {
        defference = seconds -lastintime;
        lastintime=seconds;

        if(defference<=5 && msg_count>=3)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `stackoverflow dot com` I just broke your "security." There's absolutely no way to filter humans with code.

Comment: But is there a way to prevent people from typing stackoverflow.com so it doesn't make it easy for other users to copy and paste that and put it into their own search bar? I want to make it as inconvenient for spammers as possible.

Comment: `slashdot<b></b>.<b></b>com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `click #send` function add:

```
if(message.match(/(http\:|https\:|www\.|\.com)/gi).length > 0) {
    alert("You are not allowed to use links");
    return;
}
```

Make sure to add a server-side validation as well!